# Number of inputs

Tags: c, input, error-handling, output

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int arr[10];
printf("Enter: ");
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    scanf("%d\n",&arr[i]);
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I give the input on vs code as :

*1 (enter key) 2 (enter key) 3 (enter key) 4 (enter key) 5 (enter key) v 6 (enter key) 7 (enter key)*

Then the output is shown as `123456*****` with stars containing some junk values.

I am not getting why VS Code waited for me to enter 7 then showed the output. The given loop of `scanf` will run 6 times so it should have shown the output immediately after me entering 6 then pressing enter. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: `int arr[10];` should be `int arr[10] = {0};`, otherwise you end up reading uninitialized values (random garbage) in the second loop.

Comment: @Daisy Remove the new line character in the call pf scanf  scanf("%d\n",&arr[i]); like scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Your array size is 10 which is 0-9, if you just define the array[10] there will be garbage value from 0-9. Now in first loop in which you are taking input run 6 times (0-5) it’s mean in your which array which has size 10 now have 6 input and other last 4 has garbage values. In the last loop where you printing array notice that it iterate from 0-9 means it’s print all the value but first 6 print correctly and other 4 will be garbage.

So you have to print from 0-6 instead of 0-10
Your last loop should be
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).